# In Linux Mint, how can I change Firefox to have English (US) as the default?

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, language

Firefox in Linux Mint 19 installed with or updated to English (Canada), English (United Kingdom), and English (South Africa), with English (Canada) as default.

How can I install English (United States) and make it the default?

(Note that I installed Mint as English United States UTF-8 for both Language and Region.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Firefox window's header bar (press 'alt' if it is hidden), go to

> Edit->Preferences->General->Languages

Click '`Set Alternatives`' and the `Firefox Language Settings` dialog box will come up.

Click the drop down box '`Select a language to add...`' and select `English (United States)`. Click '`Add`' to add the language to Firefox, and it should now appear as the top language in the list, meaning it is the default now for Firefox.